# Divergence theorem(problem with boundaries)

Tags: multiple-integral, divergence-theorem

I am struggling with a problem:
I have vector function such that:
$$\vec{W}=[x-z,y,z+1] $$
and surface specified by two functions:
$$z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2} $$
$$z=6-x^2+y^2$$
So this is basically enclosed surface over a vector field. Knowing that we can use a divergence theorem since:$$\vec{W}\in{C^1}(U)$$
$$U\supset  S(=\partial{\bar{V}})\cup V$$
Where:
$$\bar{V}={[(x,y,z)\in R^3:\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\le z\le 6-x^2+y^2:(x,y)\in \bar{D}]}$$
But I have no idea how can I get area D, which will be needed for integrating.How can I find intersection between cone and a  hyperbolic paraboloid ?

Comment: how did you get this equation ?

Comment: Did u notice that z=6-x^2+y^2 not z=6-x^2-y^2 ?

Comment: So we cant implement from the left side z^2=x^2+y^2

Comment: Oh sorry my mistake

Comment: Are you sure that is $z=6-x^2+y^2$ not $z=6-x^2-y^2$.because former is a hyperbolic paraboloid and $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ is a cone , So the volume enclosed is unbounded.

Comment: you might be right, so that means there is a mistake in that task :)